# Can Spring MVC handle multivalue query parameter?

Tags: spring-mvc

Having this `http://myserver/find-by-phones?phone=123&phone=345` request, is it possible to handle with something like this:

```
@Controller
public class Controller{
    @RequestMapping("/find-by-phones")
    public String find(List<String> phones){
       ...
    }
}
```

Can Spring MVC some how convert multi-value param `phones` to a list of `String`s (or other objects?

Thanks.

Alex

Comment: `find(@RequestParam(required=false, value="phone") List<String> phones)` should work. 
This works for `url?phone=123&phone=345` and also for `url?phone=123,345` and for `null` parameter value like `url` or `url?phone=`
I hope this helps anyone looking for this solution :)

Comment: If you have multiple parameters all of which can have multiple values, use a MultiValueMap.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22398892/how-to-capture-multiple-parameters-using-requestparam-using-spring-mvc

Answer (score 92, accepted):

"Arrays" in `@RequestParam` are used for binding several parameters of the same name:

```
phone=val1&phone=val2&phone=val3
```

-

```
public String method(@RequestParam(value="phone") String[] phoneArray){
    ....
}
```

You can then convert it into a list using `Arrays.asList(..)` method

EDIT1:

As suggested by emdadul, latest version of spring can do like below as well:

```
public String method(@RequestParam(value="phone", required=false) List<String> phones){
    ....
}
```

Comment: if there is not a single param out there, will phoneArray be null or be an empty array ?

Comment: Spring can put the values directly into a list: `@RequestParam(value="phone") List<String> phones`. Not sure if/when this was changed, but it works in Spring 3.0.5.

Comment: @Nailgun can you set some sort of proper default parameter and generate an empty Array or do just have to handle the null? Thank you

Comment: what about form element name will it be phone[ ] or phone or phone[0],phone[1] .....  ? I have 25 mcq questions with 4 radio button for each question.

Comment: Element name is going to be phone

Comment: `@RequestParam(value="phone", required=false) List<String> phones)` will work, `required=false` is for missing parameter cases. otherwise spring throws parameter missing error

Comment: @piechuckerr not sure about using an index like `phone[1]`, but if your 'query array' syntax looks like this: `phone[]=123&phone[]=456&phone[]=789` then the following should work: `@RequestParam(value="phone[]") List<String> phones`

Comment: @fmucar Please update your answer, as we can use List<String> phones now.

Comment: Note that if you ever want to pass in a single element that contains a comma, you're in trouble, since Spring will treat the comma as a list delimiter.  e.g. `?phone=A,B` would result in `{"A", "B"}`, not `{"A,B"}`.  It does work if there are more than one element, though, e.g. `?phone=A,B&phone=C`, which gives `{"A,B", "C"}`.

Answer (score 11):

Spring can convert the query param directly into a `List` or even a `Set`

for example:

```
 @RequestParam(value = "phone", required = false) List<String> phones
```

or

```
 @RequestParam(value = "phone", required = false) Set<String> phones
```

Answer (score 4):

I had an issue with indexed querystring like

```
http://myserver/find-by-phones?phone[0]=123&phone[1]=345
```

and only handling with

```
MultiValueMap<String, String>
```

worked for me. Neither List or String[] were handling it properly.

I also tried

```
@RequestParam("phones[]")
```

but [RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/annotation/RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.html) is looking explicitly for `phones[]` ignoring indexes. So that is why I decided to let [RequestParamMapMethodArgumentResolver](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/annotation/RequestParamMapMethodArgumentResolver.html) handle it.