# spring mvc: parse repeated request param

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

As you probably know, http supports repeated parameters, such as `http://host/file?id=1&id=2`.

In my case a Javascript element sends the ids of multiple rows in order for the server to do something with all these ids.

Is it possible for Spring MVC to give me all the ids as a collection? (List or Array)

Comment: you can have a look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9768509/can-spring-mvc-handle-multivalue-query-parameter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can map it to an array like so

```
public String getFile(@RequestParam(value="id") int[] ids){
    ...
}
```