# Spring MVC REST requestParam to handle multiple values for the same key

Tags: java, spring

I am making GET request and it has 2 parameters or basically an array

```
param {
paramNo:1,
from:mobile,
to:server
}
param {
paramNo:2,
from:server,
to:mobile
}
```

In my controller I have captured it as

```
public  @ResponseBody SearchResponse serverSearch(@RequestParam List<String> param) throws Exception {
     ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
     List<SearchInfo> searchInfo = mapper.readValue(param,new TypeReference<List<SearchInfo>>(){});
}
```

mapper.readValue does not take a List. It is throwing compilation error.

Question

1. I would prefer to retrieve it as (@RequestParam List param) rather than invoking objectMapper. What should I do convert it directly to List
2. how do I convert List to List?

Comment: How to convert `List<A>` to `List<B>`? Loop the list and convert one item at a time, if there's no collection converter.

Comment: I was hoping I can avoid looping expect the mapping to be automatically. Even if I have to loop, I still cannot do @RequestParam List<Param>, I see the following exception org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use [arrays instead of lists initially](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9768635/136363), but you can easily do a: `List<SearchInfo> params = Arrays.asList(myArray);`

### Converting JSON

If your parameters are valid JSON, as it seems from your example, it's quite simple to convert into a custom object, see [here](http://hmkcode.com/spring-mvc-json-json-to-java/).

---

### Converting something else

Otherwise you can create a custom formatter with Spring that will format the Strings that come from your request parameters into your custom objects. Basically you'll have to first create a class that registers the type of objects to format and which class does the formatting:

```
import org.springframework.format.FormatterRegistrar;
import org.springframework.format.FormatterRegistry;

public class SearchInfoFormatterRegistrar implements FormatterRegistrar {
  @Override
  public void registerFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
    registry.addFormatterForFieldType(SearchInfo.class, new SearchInfoFormatter());
  }
}
```

Then implement the class doing the formatting (mind you, this is not just casting an object to a different type, you actually have to use some logic):

```
import org.springframework.format.Formatter;

public class SearchInfoFormatter implements Formatter<SearchInfo> {
  @Override
  public String print(SearchInfo info, Locale locale) {
    // Format SearchInfo into String here.
  }

  @Override
  public SearchInfo parse(String text, Locale locale) {
    // Format String into SearchInfo here.
  }
}
```

Finally, you add them into your configuration:

```
<bean name="conversionService"
      class="org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean">
    <property name="formatterRegistrars">
        <set>
            <bean class="org.my.SearchInfoFormatterRegistrar" />
        </set>
    </property>
</bean>
```