# how to capture multiple parameters using @RequestParam using spring mvc?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, annotations

Suppose a hyperlink is clicked and an url is fired with the following parameter list `myparam=myValue1&myparam=myValue2&myparam=myValue3` . Now how can I capture all the parameters using `@RequestParam` in spring mvc?

My requirement is I have to capture all the params and put them in a map.

Please help!

Comment: Are all your parameters called "myparam"?

Answer (score 47):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "users/newuser", method = RequestMethod.POST)   
public String saveUser(@RequestParam Map<String,String> requestParams) throws Exception{
   String userName=requestParams.get("email");
   String password=requestParams.get("password");

   //perform DB operations

   return "profile";
}
```

You could use RequestParam in the above mentioned manner.

Comment: How do I make a soapui rest test for this type of map object?

Comment: What if the RequestParams is different data types?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The question is asking about parameters that have multiple values for the same name.

Answer (score 34):

It seems you can't get

```
Map<String,String>
```

because all your params have same name "myparam"

Try this instead:

```
public ModelAndView method(@RequestParam("myparam") List<String> params) { }
```

Comment: It should be '@RequestParam' rather than '@RequestRaram'. Notice the 'P' rather than 'R'. I tried using the above code and got an error and didn't catch it right away because of this subtle misspelling. Hope this helps someone. Thanks for the useful answer :)

Answer (score 21):

To get all parameters at once try this:

```
public ModelAndView postResultPage(@RequestParam MultiValueMap<String, String> params)
```

This feature is described in the `@RequestParam` java doc (3. Paragraph):

> Annotation which indicates that a method parameter should be bound to a web request parameter. Supported for annotated handler methods in Servlet and Portlet environments.
>
> If the method parameter type is Map and a request parameter name is specified, then the request parameter value is converted to a Map assuming an appropriate conversion strategy is available.
>
> **If the method parameter is `Map<String, String>` or `MultiValueMap<String, String>` and a parameter name is not specified, then the map parameter is populated with all request parameter names and values.**

Comment: Okay i got it.. I am able to get all the parameters and their values  in params,now how can i use them? please show me that..

Comment: this is best solution if you have several params with same name

Answer (score 9):

As of Spring 3.0, you can also use [MultiValueMap](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/MultiValueMap.html) to achieve this:

A rudimentary example would be:

```
public String someMethod(@RequestParam MultiValueMap<String,String> params) {

    final Iterator<Entry<String, List<String>>> it = params.entrySet().iterator();

    while(it.hasNext()) {
        final String k = it.next().getKey();
        final List<String> values = it.next().getValue();
    }

    return "dummy_response";

}
```

Comment: Do you know if Swagger is supporting this option?

Answer (score 3):

If anyone is trying to do the same in Spring Boot, use `RequestBody` in place of `RequestParam`

Answer (score 3):

Spring mvc can support `List<Object>`, `Set<Object>` and `Map<Object>` param, **but without @RequestParam**.

Take `List<Object>` as example, if your object is `User.java`, and it like this:

```
public class User {
    private String name;
    private int age;

    // getter and setter
}
```

And you want pass a param of `List<User>`, you can use url like this

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/list?users[0].name=Alice&users[0].age=26&users[1].name=Bob&users[1].age=16
```

Remember to encode the url, the url after encoded is like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/list?users%5B0%5D.name=Alice&users%5B0%5D.age=26&users%5B1%5D.name=Bob&users%5B1%5D.age=16
```

Example of `List<Object>`, `Set<Object>` and `Map<Object>` is displayed in [my github](https://github.com/Flamingo93/spring-mvc-test/blob/master/src/main/java/com/dqg/dpd/controller/Controller.java).

Comment: "but without @RequestParam" this was the key, tks.

Comment: @Frank.Chang where exactly in your Github ? The link does not show what you said...

Comment: @ jozinho22 I mean this: https://github.com/Flamingo93/spring-mvc-test/blob/master/src/main/java/com/dqg/dpd/controller/Controller.java

Answer (score 0):

You can use for multiple Params as such

```
public String saveUser(@RequestParam("email") String userName, @RequestParam("password") String password) throws Exception{
   //your code
   //perform DB operations

   return "profile";
}
```

Comment: This is not the answer of the question.

Answer (score 0):

For params with same name, you can use MultiValueMap<String ,String>. Then all the values would be present as List

Answer (score -2):

You can use multiple @RequestParam annotations as shown below.

```
@RequestParam(value="myparam1", required = true) <Datatype> myparam1,
@RequestParam(value = "myparam2", required = false) <Datatype> myparam2,
```