# Spring MVC @RequestParam a list of objects

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, http-post, httprequest

I want to create a page where a person sees a list of users and there are check boxes next to each of them that the person can click to have them deleted.

In my MVC that consumes a REST API, I want to send a List of `User` objects to the REST API.

Can the `@RequestParam` annotation support that?

For example:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.DELETE, value = "/delete")
    public @ResponseBody Integer delete(
            @RequestParam("users") List<Users> list) {
        Integer deleteCount = 0;
        for (User u : list) {
            if (u != null) {
                repo.delete(u);
                ++deleteCount;
            }
        }
        return deleteCount;
    }
```

In the MVC client, the url would be:

```
List list = new ArrayList<User>();
....
String url = "http://restapi/delete?users=" + list;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Request parameters are a Multimap of String to String. You cannot pass a complex object as request param.

But if you just pass the username that should work - see [how to capture multiple parameters using @RequestParam using spring mvc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22398892/how-to-capture-multiple-parameters-using-requestparam-using-spring-mvc)

`@RequestParam("users") List<String> list`

But I think it would be better to just use the request body to pass information.

Comment: Ahh, yes @RequestBody offers the functionality that I am looking for.

Comment: @RequestBody is not allowed on a GET for Restful APIs. This will cause problems with openapi libs like springdoc

Answer (score 5):

Spring mvc can support `List<Object>`, `Set<Object>` and `Map<Object>` param, but without @RequestParam.

Take `List<Object>` as example, if your object is `User.java`, and it like this:

```
public class User {
    private String name;
    private int age;

    // getter and setter
}
```

And you want pass a param of `List<User>`, you can use url like this

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/list?users[0].name=Alice&users[0].age=26&users[1].name=Bob&users[1].age=16
```

Remember to encode the url, the url after encoded is like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/list?users%5B0%5D.name=Alice&users%5B0%5D.age=26&users%5B1%5D.name=Bob&users%5B1%5D.age=16
```

Example of `List<Object>`, `Set<Object>` and `Map<Object>` is displayed in [my github](https://github.com/Flamingo93/spring-mvc-test).

Comment: FYI for anyone else confused like me. Using `List<User>` as parameter for the Controller won't work. Instead a wrapper class containing list should be used a parameter. Check the github link!

Comment: I can not get this to work, tried with the same code as in the github link. I am using  Spring Boot 2 and Kotlin, so it is probably one of these causing it.

Answer (score 1):

Just a reminder, any List of custom objects might require custom converters to be registered, like:

```
    @Bean
public Converter<String, CustomObject> stringToCustomObjectConverter() {
    return new Converter<>() {
        @Override
        public CustomObject convert(String str) {
            return new ObjectMapper().readValue(str, CustomObject.class);
        }
    };
}

@Bean
public Converter<String, List<CustomObject>> stringToListCustomObjectConverter() {
    return new Converter<>() {
        @Override
        public List<CustomObject> convert(String str) {
            return new ObjectMapper().readValue(str, new TypeReference<>() {
            });
        }
    };
}
```

So you can cover custom cases like:

```
 /api/some-api?custom={"name":"Bla 1","age":20}
 /api/some-api?custom={"name":"Bla 1","age":20}&custom={"name":"Bla 2","age":30}
 /api/some-api?custom=[{"name":"Bla 1","age":20},{"name":"Bla 2","age":30}]
```

where: @RequestParam("custom") List customObjects