# why List<String> is always returning size 1 in this case

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I want to send selected options of a select to controller using following

```
<form action="/save" method="POST" >             
         <input type="text" name="name"/>
         <label>Subjects</label>
         <select name="subjects">
            <option value="English">English</option>
            <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
         </select>

     <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

In controller while form is posted I check the size of subjects list

```
@RequestMapping(params={"subjects"}, value = "/save-std", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveStd(@ModelAttribute("std")Student std,
            @RequestParam("subjects") List<String> subjects) {
        System.out.println("List Size is " + subjects.size() );         
        return "home";
    }
```

it always shows `List Size is 1` in the console, why it happens or any better solution to get all selected options?

Comment: Sorry for 'seats' instead of 'subjects' I have quite messy code so added here part of that so it could be a clear one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33354534/spring-mvc-requestparam-a-list-of-objects). This may help you.

> "Request parameters are a Multimap of String to String. You cannot
>   pass a complex object as request param."

Comment: I think there should be other approach!

Comment: In that link itself they have mentioned you can use @RequestBody