# Spring Rest : pass an object in RequestParam

Tags: java, spring

I want to pass a list of objects in my request through @RequestParam but it doesn't work.
If I do :

```
 public List<Affaire> getAllAffaires(
                 @RequestParam(value = "consultantId", required = false) Long consultantId,
                 @RequestParam(value = "filtres", required = false) List<FilterDTO> filtres)
```

It doesnt go into the method, I get a 500 Error.
If I do :

```
 public List<Affaire> getAllAffaires(
                 @RequestParam(value = "consultantId", required = false) Long consultantId,
                 List<FilterDTO> filtres)
```

I am getting a :

```
Unable to evaluate the expression Method threw 'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException' exception.
```

If I pass another object which contains the list as :

```
 public List<Affaire> getAllAffaires(
                 @RequestParam(value = "consultantId", required = false) Long consultantId,
                 FilterDTOList filtres)
```

I get into the method but the property listFiltre of FilterDTOList is always null.

In Front Side (AngularJS) the call is :

```
function Affaire ($resource, DateUtils) {
        var resourceUrl =  'api/affaires/:id';

        return $resource(resourceUrl, {}, {
            'query': { method: 'GET', isArray: true,
                params:{
                    consultantId:'@consultantId',
                    filtres:'@filtres'
                },
```

How can I do pass my List as a parameter of my request?

Comment: User `@RequestBody FilterDTOList filtres` and pass filters in request body.

Comment: Could you provide more information? How are you doing the request to the service? Which HTTP verb are you using?

Comment: Can you provide stacktrace when 500 is thrown in the first example? It looks like there is no mapping defined for FilterDTO. Probably, if you inject request param to List<String> and then map from String to FilterDTO, it will work but it's hard to tell without additional context

Comment: there is not stacktrace , it seems that it doesnt even go into the java method.

Answer (score 0):

try with array instead of List and then convert that array to List

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/updateAllAffaires")
    @ResponseBody
    public List<FilterDTO> getSelectedGenes(@RequestParam(value = "consultantId", required = false) Long consultantId,
                                            @RequestBody FilterDTO[] filtersDto) {
        List<FilterDTO> filters = new ArrayList<>();
        // here you can use the logic to convert array to list
        return filters;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using @ModelAttribute or @Requestbody instead of @RequestParam.

```
public List<Affaire> getAllAffaires(
             @RequestParam(value = "consultantId", required = false) Long consultantId,
             @ModelAttribute(value = "filtres", required = false) List<FilterDTO> filtres)
```

You can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29370581/spring-mvc-please-explain-difference-between-requestparam-and-modelattribute) answer for better understanding. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33354534/spring-mvc-requestparam-a-list-of-objects) will also help.