# Spring — Passing collection of objects as URL parameters

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

Is it possible with GET Rest Method to pass collection of objects as URL parameters?

```
class Person{
  String name;
  String surname;
  ...
}
```

```
public ResponseEntity<List<PersonInfo>> getInfoAboutPersons(@RequestParam List<Person> persons)
```

I try to send JSON as string and parse it. I became: "Invalid character found in the request target. The valid characters are defined in RFC 7230 and RFC 3986", because of '[', ']'.

My only solution is pass list of String (name,surname) and then split and convert to objects, what is not really elegance.

Can someone help by example?

Comment: No, you need to `POST` for that data.

Comment: Also you may consider sending the JSON string in the `@RequestBody` .

Comment: you should check @brian answer on this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22398892/how-to-capture-multiple-parameters-using-requestparam-using-spring-mvc

Comment: @NavinGelot Ok, but how to call it in postman?

Comment: I think you could [URLEncode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) your URL String, although the correct way to do it is using `POST` instead of `GET`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Spring MVC handle multivalue query parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9768509/can-spring-mvc-handle-multivalue-query-parameter)

Comment: Another duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22398892/how-to-capture-multiple-parameters-using-requestparam-using-spring-mvc

Comment: @Jannis Those posts are about List of Strings, but I need list of object with few fields.

Comment: Missed that @MateuszNowakowski