# How do I handle an unknown number of RequestParams in Spring Boot REST?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, http-request-parameters

I have a REST api in Spring Boot:

```
@GetMapping("/test")
public MyClass getData() { 

    return something;
}
```

This endpoint can be requested with up to 10 RequestParams. I know of course all of the 10 possible RequestParams, however client can chose to request with anywhere between 0 to all 10 of the RequestParams.

Now I need a way to handle this without plugging all 10 RequestParams in as parameters in the getData() method. Is it not possible to register all possible RequestParams in a class, and the use that class as parameter ing the getData()?

Something like this:

```
public class ParamClass {
    private @RequestParam("ParamOne") String ParamOne;
    private @RequestParam("ParamTwo") Set<String> ParamTwo;
    private @RequestParam("ParamThree") Integer ParamThree;
}
```

And then

```
@GetMapping("/test")
public MyClass getData(@RequestParam ParamClass params) { 

    return something;
}
```

**Please note: The parameters can be different types (String, int, Set, etc.) therefore the following solution comes very close but does not solve it because the map requires a consistent value type: [how to capture multiple parameters using @RequestParam using spring mvc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22398892/how-to-capture-multiple-parameters-using-requestparam-using-spring-mvc)**

Answer (score 1):

One way to do that would be receive a Map with the params, the problem is that all the params would have the same type, and you would have to cast to the proper type in your code:

```
@ResponseBody
public String updateFoos(@RequestParam Map<String,Object> allParams) {
    return "Parameters are " + allParams.entrySet();
}
```

Comment: The disadvantage of this is that the 10 known parameters are now un-typed, so I wouldn't recommend this approach. It's how you would do it if the parameters are dynamic, i.e. the names are unknown at compile-time, but for 10 well-known but optional parameters, this is the wrong way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can define all parameters in your method and set them as '***not required***'.

```
@GetMapping("/test")
public MyClass getData(@RequestParam(name="p1", required=false) String p1,
    @RequestParam(name="p2", required=false) Integer p2,
    ...) { 
    return something;
}
```

Then you can choose which parameters to define in your url. The others are null. Or you define a default-value in the `RequestParam`-Annotation.

Comment: Thank you, I already know that... I am asking: "...I need a way to handle this without plugging all 10 RequestParams in as parameters in the getData() method"

Comment: @Ben You said *"client can chose to request with anywhere between 0 to all 10 of the RequestParams"*, which means you need all 10, so why not use the automatic conversion to declared parameter type you get for free when using `@RequestParam`? Asking not to have to declared all 10 doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

you can use @RequestBody annotation. It will map the HttpRequest body to class object.
As spring boot has jackson in its classpath, it will do automatic deserialization of the inbound HttpRequest body onto a Java object.

```
public class ParamClass {
 String paramOne;
 String paramTwo;
 ....
 String paramTem;
 
 // default constructor
 
 // all getters
 // all setters
```

}

```
@PostMapping("/test")
public MyClass getData(@RequestBody ParamClass params) { 

    return something;
}
```

Client should send json data to the api /test

Comment: I was looking for something like this, but it does not work.. It says "Required request body is missing"

Comment: Hi @Ben,
please check I have updated the code.
Changed @GetMapping("/test")
to 
@PostMapping("/test")

So you have to send POST request from you ajax request.
For example, if you are using JQuery,
you can use,

Comment: Hi @Ben,

have to send POST request from you ajax request.
For example, if you are using JQuery,
you can use something like

`var data ={
"paramOne":"value 1",
"paramTwo":"value 2"
}

$.ajax({
 url : 'your-post-url',
 type : "POST",
 data : JSON.stringify(data),
 contentType : 'application/json',
 dataType : 'json',
 success : function(result) {
 //success handler code here
 }
});`

you can use simple rest api tool like https://restapi.tools/