# How one can know how @RequestParam works with arrays?

Tags: spring, documentation

I have read here https://stackoverflow.com/a/9768635/258483 that Spring MVC will populate an array with multiple values of single name parameter.

But how would I know this without experiment or without asking SO?

The [Javadoc about @RequestParam](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html) is very poor and contain no word about arrays.

What is the full and reliable information source on the topic?

Answer (score 0):

[RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/annotation/RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.html) Resolves method arguments annotated with `@RequestParam`, which extends [AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/annotation/AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.html). `AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver` creates a `WebDataBinder`  to apply type conversion to the resolved argument value if it doesn't match the method parameter type. Lets take a look at some part of `resolveArguemnt` method:

```
            try {
                arg = binder.convertIfNecessary(arg, paramType, parameter);
            }
            catch (ConversionNotSupportedException ex) {
                throw new MethodArgumentConversionNotSupportedException(arg, ex.getRequiredType(),
                        namedValueInfo.name, parameter, ex.getCause());
            }
            catch (TypeMismatchException ex) {
                throw new MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException(arg, ex.getRequiredType(),
                        namedValueInfo.name, parameter, ex.getCause());
```

For `RequestParam`, `binder.convertIfNecessary` uses up to 116 different `Converter`s to possibly convert from passed `String` to required param, e.g. `List`. Some of possible conversions are:

- String => Enum
- String => Properties
- String => Collection

I guess the only way to debug `resolveArgument` method.